# Debugging a crash

Tags: vb.net

I am normally pretty good about debugging errors based on the exception message, but this one has me stumped. Can someone take a look and give me some advise? The application works on 9 out of 10 computers. 1 computer I have loaded it on gives this error, all other work fine. Systems are the same to my knowledge.

Application crashes when clicking the 'GO' button, when doing that, it attaches itself to Outlook and sends an email.

**Error:**

```
> ************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at SickPrinter.Form1.Go_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Search a working computer's registry for CLSID `0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046` to find out what app it relates to. My guess is that the app isn't installed on the rogue machine.

Comment: In my system this key belongs to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C` Looks like something with your outlook activation

Comment: @T.S. This application does attach to outlook via Interop.Outlook. The weird part is it DID work at one point on said machine. Just recently is when it decided it was not going to.

Comment: Outlook or some other library changed? May be you using outlook and interop from different versions?